# Eliminar texto dentro de corchetes en javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo el siguiente simple código:

```
<input id="nick" type="text"/>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById('nick').value

</script>
```

Necesito eliminar una parte del nombre, sólo si posee corchetes `[]`.
O sea que si tiene este nombre: `'Hola soy juan [soy pro]'`,
quedaría como esto: `'Hola soy juan'`.

Comment: Tendrias que recorrer tu string caracter por caracter para que cuando encuentre el corchete que abre, entre a otra función que ahora busque el corchete que cierra para tener la ubicación de ambos y elimnar todo en esas posiciones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Una alternativa es el uso de `replace` en conjunto con la expresión regular<sup>1</sup> `/\[.+?]/g` donde:

- `\[`: escapar la corchete de apertura.
- `.` : Cualquier caracter
- `+` : Uno o más caracteres iguales al previo
- `?` : Tacaño, el menor número de veces
- `g` : Global

> <sup>1</sup> Por expresión regular me estoy refiriendo a un objeto RegEx. Así como los objeto Array al ser declarados usando la forma corta, `[elemento1,elmento2]`, no llevan comillas, tampoco lo llevan los objetos RegEx `/expresionregular/banderas`.

En el siguiente código, se incluyen dos casos, uno similar al indicado por el OP y otro un poco más complejo.

```js
//Caso simple, una sóla ocurrencia
var texto1 = "Conservar este texto [eliminar este] pero convervar esto otro";

//Caso complejo, varias ocurrencias no consecutivas
var texto2 = "manzana [melón] melocotón [membrillo] mora";

// Asignar la expresión regular propuesta a una variable
var re = /\[.+?]/g;

//Realizar la eliminación mediante reemplazar para los dos casos.
var salida1 = texto1.replace(re,'');
var salida2 = texto2.replace(re,'');

//Agregar el resultado a la página
document.write('Caso 1: ' + salida1 + '<br/>Caso 2: ' + salida2);
```

Comment: Buen aporte pero, en `var re` te faltan comillas, ¿cierto?

Comment: @ErlantzCalvo: jeje, cuando ví algo así por primera vez pensé lo mismo, pero no, no faltan las comillas. Se trata de un objeto de tipo expresión regular (RegExp), no de un objeto tipo cadena (String).

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar substr y replace en un loop para eliminar todos los textos que estén dentro de `[ ]`

Por ejemplo, si intentas **'Javier [el mejor] de [su casa en] Panama'**, el resultado sera **`Javier de Panama`**

Luego eliminamos todos los espacios repetidos con el código

**`output.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();`**

Espero te sirva

```js
var example = document.getElementById('example'),
     result = document.getElementById('result');
     

  example.addEventListener('keyup',function() {
    var output = this.value,
        finish = false;
    
    while(!finish) {
      if(output.indexOf('[') >=0 && output.indexOf(']') >= 0) {
        output = output.replace(output.substr(output.indexOf('['), output.indexOf(']')  - output.indexOf('[') + 1),'');
      }
      else {
        finish = true;
      }
    }

    result.innerText = output.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="example" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ya lo he hecho por si a alguien le interesa:**

```js
var c = "Hola amigos [quiero que me eliminen]";
var d = c.split('');
var buscar1 = d.indexOf('[');
buscar1 = parseInt(buscar1);
var buscar2 = d.indexOf(']');
buscar2 = parseInt(buscar2);
var total = buscar2 - buscar1;
var eliminar = d.splice(buscar1, (total +1));
var g = d.join('');


document.write(g);
```

Comment: No sé quien te puso el voto negativo, pero supongo que fue debido a que no se incluye ninguna descripción o explicación.

Comment: +1 - te felicito, lograste resolver el problema sin embargo es bueno aprender de las cosas buenas de los demás y el ejemplo de @Ruben es excelente, merece que des a su respuesta como aceptada, Saludos!! ;))....